Cycle decomposition of $\sigma = (1 ,2,3)(2 ,3, 4 ,5 ,6)(5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10)$
I'm trying to write $\sigma = (1, 2, 3)(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)$ as a product of disjoint cycles. I believed the answer to be $(1, 2)(3, 4, 5, 6)(7, 8, 9, 10)$ however it is supposed to be $(1, 2)(3, 4, 5)(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)$. Can someone please explain why in the second cycle 5 doesn't get mapped to 6, but to 3 instead? It seemed logical to me that 5 would get mapped to 6 as it was similar to what happened before, namely that 3 got mapped to 4 and that 4 got mapped to 5.
Thank you!

What you wrote it is "supposed" to be also can't be a correct answer, as the cycles are not disjoint. ($1$ appears twice there) In any case, composition of permutations is usually done from right to left, like any composition of functions. If we follow the permutations, we see that $5\to 6\to 2\to 3$. So $5$ is indeed mapped to $3$.

Sorry, that second 1 is supposed to be a 10, I'll clear that up in my question.

Ok, then this answer indeed looks correct. See my explanation above.

I'm not completely clear on how you know where a number finally gets mapped to. For example, for 5 to get mapped to 3 it took 3 transitions. However, we can say 4 gets mapped to 5, which is only one transition. Put informally, how do you know when you've gone through enough transitions to say that number x gets mapped to number y?

We have a composition of $3$ functions here. So it is always $3$ transitions. For an element $a$, we look where the right permutation maps it, then where the next permutation maps its image, and finally where the left permutation maps the result. With $4$ we have $4\to 4\to 5\to 5$. The right permutation maps $4$ to itself, the left maps $5$ to itself. So these are still $3$ transitions, we just don't write elements that are mapped to themselves.

You can map this out step-by-step in multi-line permutation notation. The first line is the unpermuted numbers, and is the reference for each of the cycle notations. The other lines show the permuted state. As Mark indicates we start with the right-most cycle $(5,6,7,8,9,10)$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\1&2&3&4&10&5&6&7&8&9\end{bmatrix}$$
Then we apply the cycle $(2,3,4,5,6)$, adding a new line:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\1&2&3&4&10&5&6&7&8&9\\1&5&2&3&4&10&6&7&8&9\end{bmatrix}$$
And finally apply $(1,2,3)$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\1&2&3&4&10&5&6&7&8&9\\1&5&2&3&4&10&6&7&8&9\\2&1&5&3&4&10&6&7&8&9\end{bmatrix}$$
By comparing the first and last lines, we can break it back into cycles: $$(1,2)(3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)$$

using $(a_1 ... a_n) = (a_1 a_2)(a_2 a_3)...(a_{n-1} a_{n})$
get $\sigma = (1, 2, 3)(2 ,3, 4 ,5 ,6)(5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10)$
$=[(1, 2)(2,3)][(2 ,3)(3, 4 ,5)(5 ,6)][(5 ,6)(6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10)]$
$=(1,2)(3, 4 ,5)(6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10)$
